# Rails 4 testing bug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Situation: if we add two identic line items into a cart, we update line item quantity instead of adding a duplicate.In browser everything works fine but in unit testing section something fails because of an empty cycle in code. Which I wanted to use to update all prices. Why? Is that a unit test engine bug?

LineItem.all  and cart.line_items in process of testing produce two DIFFERENT structures.

```
#<LineItem id: 980190964, product_id: 1, cart_id: 999, created_at: "2014-06-01 00:21:28",   updated_at: "2014-06-01 00:21:28", quantity: 2, price: #<BigDecimal:ba0fb544,'0.4E1',9(27)>>

#<LineItem id: 980190964, product_id: 1, cart_id: 999, created_at: "2014-06-01 00:21:28", updated_at: "2014-06-01 00:21:28", quantity: 1, price: #<BigDecimal:ba0d1b04,'0.4E1',9(27)>>
```

cart.line_items guy did not update quantity

Code itself (produces LineItem which is then saved in line_item_controller which calls this method)

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
 def add_product(product_id)
   # LOOK THIS CYCLE BREAKS UNIT TEST, SRSLY, I MEAN IT
     line_items.each do |item|
   end  

 current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product_id)
 fresh_price = Product.find_by(id: product_id).price    
 if current_item
    current_item.quantity += 1
 else
    current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id, price: fresh_price)
 end

 return current_item
end
...
```

Unit test code

```
test "non-unique item added" do
 cart = Cart.create(:id => 999)
 line_item0 = cart.add_product(2)
 line_item0.save
 line_item1 = cart.add_product(1)
 line_item1.save    
   assert_equal 2, cart.line_items.size #success
 line_item2 = cart.add_product(1)
 line_item2.save
   assert_equal 2, cart.line_items.size, "what?"
   assert cart.total_price > 15 #fail, prices are not enough, quantity of product1 = 1
 #we get total price from quantity, it's  a simple method in model
end
```

And once again: IT DOES WORK in browser as it should. Even with cycle. I feel so dumb right now...

I tried using **existing** cart with id=777 from a fixture. Did not help. LineItems.all still has correct line item, cart still doesn't update quantity. So it's not a saving problem, I guess.

Comment: What do you do in the cycle? Also: indent your code please. We are supposed to read this, no?

Comment: How do you indent code?

Comment: Okay. Now I know how to indent code. I'm doing NOTHING in the cycle. Literally. But I was going to update all prices in cart with it. Just in case product prices changes.